# Round/format numbers in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure, daxstudio

I am trying to round numbers using the code below, which does round the number to `9M`  if the number has decimals `9,000,000.55`, but if the number is `9,000,000` it does not round. How to get around this? many thanks in advance.

```
SWITCH(
TRUE(),
_sales >= 1000000, FORMAT( _sales, "$#,##0,,M"),
_sales >= 1000, FORMAT( _sales, "$#,##0,k"),
FORMAT( _sales, "$#,##0" )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Here you go.

```
Column = SWITCH(
TRUE(),
ABS([_sales]) >= 1000000, FORMAT( [_sales], "$#,##0,,M"),
ABS([_sales]) >= 1000, FORMAT( [_sales], "$#,##0,k"),
FORMAT( [_sales], "$#,##0" )

)
```

The code works fine as far as I can see.

[image]

Comment: my bad it fails when the number is -9,000,000

Comment: I'll update now.